# Cannot set Border of Undefined - JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate some code via javascript. The drama I am having is that I receive an

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'border' of undefined".

I am new to javascript and trying to get a full understanding of why this happens and how to prevent this in future coding projects. My goal is if the validation fails it changes the text box border to red.

```
function validation_Step1(event) {
    var Firstbox = document.getElementsByName("Firstbox");

    if (Firstbox.value == null || Firstbox.value == '') {
        document.getElementsByName("Firstbox")
            .style.border = "2px solid red";
        alert("Error");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: getElementsByName does not return a single element, but a NodeList - so you have to access the element(s) inside it individually, for example using the index notation.

Comment: [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) Returns a nodelist collection...

Comment: is there any element with attribute name as `Firstbox` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `document.getElementsByName("Firstbox")` returns a `NodeList` which can be seen as a "kind of" array.

You should do `document.getElementsByName("Firstbox")[0]` if you want to manipulate the first element only

Comment: _"returns an array"_ ? No, it is not an `array`

Comment: The object it returns has many things in common with an array, but it definitely isn't one.

Comment: Ok, it's a NodeList, but for a begginer, the difference are not really meaningful. Anyway, I'll change my answer to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, however when i try to assign the value of the box to check the string(input) it won't retrieve the value. I used alert to see what was in this and it alerts [ObjectNodeList]. I have tried to retrieve the value from the node list but not much luck..

Answer (score -2):

To find elements use ids:

```
<input type="text" id="login">
```

Then get the element:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('login');
```

Also run JS scripts when whole HTML has been loaded, use onload event in JS.